# Uploading file with type="button"

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to automate a website to do some daily task with python selenium. I need to upload a file in the process. I have been doing some research on it and have realized that when people inspect on the "choose file" button it has a type of "file". For me I have a type of "button". So I  tried to change the type to file and it worked fine. But of course I shouldn't have to change the  html code every time. Here is my code:

```
brow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/button').send_keys('/Users/test/Subtitle_1.srt')
```

If you were wondering the error I get when I run this wellll, I don't get any and nothing happens. So since it is a type button I tried clicking on it then sending the keys to upload the file:

```
brow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/button').click()
brow.send_keys('/Users/test/Subtitle_1.srt')
```

and it gave me an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 110, in <module>
    brow.send_keys('/Users/test/Subtitle_1.srt')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Does anyone know how I can upload a file with a type button?

[image]

One more thing to help y'all out with answering my question, here is a code that works, it only works because the choose file btn contains
type="file". Feel free to try the code out(change the path of the file):

```
#import modules
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/test/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu/ex/fup.html')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/input[1]').send_keys('/Users/test/Subtitle_1.srt')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/input[3]').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code like :

```
uploadBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="profilePicture"]')
uploadBtn.send_keys(localPathOfFile)
```

It's working for me vey well !

--- EDIT ---

You said that when the button type is file and not button, it works so I'm offering you this solution.

It allows you to change the attribute of the button.

With ID:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('browBtn').setAttribute('type','file');");
```

Or with XPath:

```
driver.execute_script("document.evaluate(yourXpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.setAttribute('type','file');");
```

And you go from this

```
<button id="browBtn" type="button" name="button">Browse</button>
```

to this :

```
<button id="browBtn" type="file" name="button">Browse</button>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216412/discussion-on-answer-by-dusart-victor-uploading-file-with-typebutton).